# Use or not Key as both FK and PK

Tags: sql, t-sql

On a database I have the following:

```
USERS
Id (PK)
Name

DOCTORS
Id (PK)
UserId (FK)
CurriculumVitae
Birthdate
...
```

All doctors I also Users of the application but have extra columns and I am displaying all doctors on a page.

Does it make sense to have Id and UserId on DOCTORS table?

Or should I make UserId both the PK and FK of table DOCTORS:

```
DOCTORS
UserId (PK, FK)
CurriculumVitae
Birthdate
...
```

In your opinion when should I go for this option?

Comment: Are the two columns always going to be the same? Or does the doctor have a `UserId` as well as a separate `Id`?

Comment: @mypetlion I believe that is the question. To have a single id across the two tables, or a second?

Comment: I would imagine doctors to users would be a one-to-one relationship (more than one user cannot be the same doctor, unless i am missing something). In that case, making the UserId a PK and FK makes sense. I would also consider moving birthdate to Users since all users have a birthday... just a thought

Comment: Both User.Id and Doctor.Id are defined as "int identity". Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make `UserId` (as you have defined it) both the primary key and foreign key.  The primary key specifies that it is unique within the table.  The foreign key maps it back to the `Users` table.

This is an example of a subsetting relationship.

I would actually call the columns `Users.UserId` and `Doctors.DoctorId`.  I think that is less confusing nomenclature that captures the most important aspect of the two columns.  However, the actual names are not important for your question (and yours are reasonable).

Comment: Yeah, and Java ORMs can usually map those tables as one inheriting from the other one. I'm sure other languages do something similar too.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not make it a PK also then you could have duplicates which is probably not what you want.